Client authentication failed: client_id
I am following the book
Spring Security in Action, Second Edition Chapter 14.2 Running the authorization code grant type.
I believe that I followed the instructions clearly, but I keep getting an exception
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: client_id

This is my flow. Fetch the code from the first url, afterwards, I use the code and pass it in my curl request
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://www.manning.com/authorized&code_challenge=Ys2R6lAx2idjbr_mVPYzweT2loaYVBPvUKBaeu3zDgo&code_challenge_method=S256

curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token?client_id=client&redirect_uri=https://www.manning.com/authorized&grant_type=authorization_code&code=lCC4um4ivSSAvXRtldrs8bWZV-Lre7HGOKjFnpifnZMTtZA6FGR7nxVXfNwVYX0koYfX0V7ejU9hm3birOzt_3nO1MAhiBuIx2rcWPQ9YXVqnUuWxGmWVrRfo0Q3gvR2&code_verifier=Uj0Kh6iiJvuEPKQcEnejWB9__bxCY-XwglkymMyXlJo' --header 'Authorization: Basic YmlsbDpwYXNzd29yZA=='

Here is my configuration
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain asFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {


        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration
                .applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.exceptionHandling((e) ->
                e.authenticationEntryPoint(
                        new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("bill")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();

    }


    /*
    * code_challenge=QYPAZ5NU8yvtlQ…—If using the authorization code enhanced with PKCE
    * (discussed in chapter 13), you must provide the code challenge with the authorization request.
    * When requesting the token, the client must send the verifier pair to prove they are the same application
    * that initially sent this request. The PKCE flow is enabled by default.
    * */

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient
        .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId("client")
        .clientSecret("secret")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(
                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(
                AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .redirectUri("https://www.manning.com/authorized")
                .tokenSettings(
                        TokenSettings.builder()
                                .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE)
                                .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(24))
                                .build()
                )
        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
        .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        RSAPublicKey publicKey =
                (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey =
                (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
        .privateKey(privateKey)
        .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {

        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .build();
    }
}


In your RegisteredClientRepository you set the clientId as client and clientSecret as secret.
In your CURL request you pass:
--header 'Authorization: Basic YmlsbDpwYXNzd29yZA=='
Which when decoded is: bill:password. This needs to be client:secret, which is Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==
